# Optimize laravel leftJoin with distance computation

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

My below code works fine but it takes at least 3 sec to give results.Is it possible to make faster query with same results without laravel eager loading.

```
    $value =  User::whereIn('plan_id',['mprom03','mproy06'])
    ->leftJoin('locations as l', 'users.id', '=', 'l.user_id')
    ->leftJoin('abouts', 'users.id', '=', 'abouts.user_id')
    ->leftJoin('appearances', 'users.id', '=', 'appearances.user_id')
    ->leftJoin('sexes', 'users.id', '=', 'sexes.user_id')       
    ->select('users.*','appearances.age','appearances.weight','appearances.height','sexes.oral','sexes.size', DB::raw('ROUND(6371 * acos(cos(radians(' . $cordiante[0] . ')) * cos(radians(`latitude`)) * cos(radians(`longitude`) - radians(' . $cordiante[1] . ')) + sin(radians(' . $cordiante[0] . ')) * sin(radians(`latitude`)))) as distance'))

    ->orderByRaw('RAND()')->limit(20)->get();
```

Comment: Probably - your first step is going to be looking at what indexes you have.

Comment: The query you have is a join and its not using eager loading as far as provided code snippet is concerned.

Can you post output of `show create table locations ` and `show index from locations ` from MySQL client?